# Errno 22 Invalid argument when trying to export dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to export my dataframe to excel (in Windows). My code looks like this:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

clients_file = pd.read_excel("count.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", header=0)
clients_file.to_excel(os.path.join("path", "backup", "weekly", "12345", "12345" + "_" + pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')) + ".xlsx", index=False, sheet_name="report")
```

My problem is that I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'path\\backup\\weekly\\12345\\12345_2022-03-03-12:10:56.xlsx'
```

and I don't know really why. I know that I can use "+" to join strings, but path.join is nicer to read. Any ideas ? Cheers!

Comment: If you are doing this in windows, the character `:` is not allowed in a file name.

Comment: @nonDucor I changed `:` to `-`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @nonDucor can you add your comment as an answer ? Changing `:` to `-` worked, because now I get other error which is easy to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this in Windows, `:` is not allowed as part of a file name. A suggestion:

```py
date_str = pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'))
clients_file.to_excel(os.path.join("path", 
                                   "backup", 
                                   "weekly", 
                                   "12345", 
                                   "12345_" + date_str + ".xlsx", 
                      index=False, 
                      sheet_name="report")
```